# Weird crashes on [UITableViewSectionElement accessibilityChildren]

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit, uiaccessibility

We just released a new app last week on the appstore, and we are receiving a lot of weird crashes in testflight.

We got about 8 differents crashes (with pretty much the same stack-traces) in testflight with 5 users max each (with around 3k users total) and around 200/250 occurences total.
As no one complain to us throug appstore comments or email about reccurent crash, we think it's maybe something with background fetch (we use this to update data within the app).

We also look around accessibility options as the stack trace mention UIAccessibility but weren't able to reproduce this crashes.
Idem for UITableViewSectionElement (we use sections header on UITableCiew) but without success. We tought about reloaddata method call from an bakcground thread, but the error would be something more explicit.

Does anyone had this kind of issues? Or at least any ideas about what is happening?

Here is the stack-trace : [image: Stack-trace]

Comment: Try enabling VoiceOver and swiping vertically with three fingers to advance through the table view. That might help to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Apparently I didn't try this enough before. I'm able to reproduce crashes now. Thanks.